Cannot get transactions returned by w3.eth.filter("pending")
I have code listening at testnet node and getting pending transactions returned by filter. It works well, usually, but sometimes filter returns id (or batch of ids) of non existent transactions. Or transactions disapearing from mempool before I can get them? What can be reason of such behaviour? I'd like to be sure it is not my bug ;).
def handle_event(self, event: str):
    transaction = None
    try:
        # TX not found here
        transaction = self.w3.eth.get_transaction(event)
    except Exception as excpt:
        LOG.error("handle_event, error while getting transaction: %s", excpt)

    # TX handling ...

async def log_loop(self, event_filter, poll_interval):

    while True:
        for event in event_filter.get_new_entries():
            self.handle_event(event)
        await asyncio.sleep(poll_interval)

def run(self):

    tx_filter = self.w3.eth.filter("pending")
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(self.log_loop(tx_filter, MEMPOOL_POLL_INTERVAL)))
    finally:
        loop.close()


Hi, it would be good to post the code you are using. It makes it easier to help!

Added code, it is inspired by googled examples heavilly...

When you say a test node is it your node or from a provider? If not your node, look at using getLogs instead of filters.

It is my GETH node connected to Sepolia.
